# Use unique values from a column range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I made a script to create folders and files in these specific folders.
The script works just fine but I can't use the unique values from a column range (the folders and files get the name of all the range - separated with coma) - I need that the `A1` value in the range be the name of the first folder (and the same name of its files), `A2` value be the name of the second folder (and its files), and so on...

What can I do to solve this?

```
function myFunction() {    
    var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var data = aa.getDataRange().getValues();

    var pasta = DriveApp.createFolder(data);
    DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1B9ZGsFr8j0RW82NTRQejd5bmM').addFolder( pasta );
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(pasta);

    var doc = DocumentApp.create(data);
    docFile = DriveApp.getFileById( doc.getId() );
    DriveApp.getFolderById( pasta.getId() ).addFile( docFile );
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);

    docsheet = DriveApp.getFileById('1zSpgQv5u9kvTu9H9kCwh9yUTUgtJ8x9fJLke7_VDCws');
    var dodo = docsheet.makeCopy().setName(data);
    DriveApp.getFolderById( pasta.getId() ).addFile( dodo );
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(dodo);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something along the lines of

```js
function myFunction() {    
  var aa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = aa.getDataRange().getValues();

  data.map(function(row) {  // Get only column A
    return row[0];
  }).filter(function(x, i, s) { // If the index is smaller we have a duplicate
    return s.indexOf(x) === i;
  }).forEach(function(name){

    // Create the folder
    var pasta = DriveApp.createFolder(name);
    DriveApp.getFolderById('0B1B9ZGsFr8j0RW82NTRQejd5bmM').addFolder(pasta);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFolder(pasta);

    // Create the doc var doc = DocumentApp.create(name);
    docFile = DriveApp.getFileById( doc.getId() );
    DriveApp.getFolderById(pasta.getId()).addFile(docFile);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(docFile);

    // Copy docsheet
    docsheet = DriveApp.getFileById('1zSpgQv5u9kvTu9H9kCwh9yUTUgtJ8x9fJLke7_VDCws');
    var dodo = docsheet.makeCopy().setName(name);
    DriveApp.getFolderById(pasta.getId()).addFile(dodo);
    DriveApp.getRootFolder().removeFile(dodo);
  });    
}
```